# Why am I getting the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<div id="opening_0" style="background-color: #bfbfbf; position: absolute; left: 45px; top: 45px; height: 202.5px; width: 157.5px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 4;" ondrop="drop(event, this)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" onclick="photos_add_selected_fid(this);">&nbsp;</div>
```

Javascript:

```
canvas.style.left = $("#opening_0").style.left - img.width + "px"; 
canvas.style.top = $("#opening_0").style.top - img.height + "px";
```

Why am I getting this error"?

Comment: why are you using jquery when you dont use the .css() function?

Comment: I'm new to using jquery, so my code is a mix between using it and not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery's .css() function because thats basically why you use jQuery:

```
canvas.style.left = parseInt($("#opening_0").css('left')) - img.width + "px";
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is because `$("#opening_0")` returns a jQuery object which wraps the matched DOM nodes. To get to the underlying DOM nodes, you can treat it like an array: `$("#opening_0")[0]` will work, for example.

*But*, this approach won't work well, since `style.left` will return a string which could have px or percentage values. You could use `$("#opening_0").offset().left` instead which will always return a numerical value.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery objects do not have a `style` property.

If you want to have access to it, either use the vanilla javascript way:

```
document.getElementById("opening_0").style.left;
```

...or "unwrap" the jQuery object like so:

```
$("#opening_0")[0].style.left;
```

I'd recommend using the first method. Just remember to parse the value by using `parseInt()`.

Comment: I guess the downvote is because you basically said the exact same thing as Nevett’s answer, only three minutes later.

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert: It is different from his answer.

Comment: Different how? Both answers explain: 1. that the confusion arises because the OP wanted to use a DOM property on a jQuery object and how to resolve it (by getting to the DOM object) and 2. that the CSS value has to be parsed before it can be used as a number. I don’t see anything substantial that you’ve added. Additionally, using `parseInt` could yield false results because the unit may not be `px` as expected whereas `offset` (Nevett’s solution) always works with pixels.

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert: The answer points out the same problem (which is extremely common, I would even say necessary) but provides a different solution by using vanilla Javascript, and then suggests an alternative solution which yes, has also been posted (it didn't occur to you that we could have both started writing an answer at the same time, but I finished mine 3 minutes later?). There is absolutely no reason to downvote such answer.

Comment: First of all: I was not the one who down-voted your answer so you don’t have to be angry with me. Fortunately, stackoverflow is quite nice and shows you that there have been new answers while you are writing your own. Many times I’ve had to discard (or rewrite) a post because someone else was quicker. It’s not a nice feeling, I know, but try to think of the reader (might not be the OP) who has to go through all those duplicate (or subtly different) answers in order to find the one that actually contains the solution to their problem. It’s cleaner to amend the `getElementById` way in a comment.

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert: I'm not angry at all